# Is there any way to highlight a block of code in VS2012?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

Highlight a block of text by selecting the lines you want, doing a right click, and then choosing a background color.

It would look something like this:

[image]

Comment: I am not aware of such functionality. Why do you need this? There might be something better.

Comment: It would be nice to highlight the background so the section is easy to see when you are searching for it.

Comment: You'd need this feature when you write monster methods.  A good guideline is that one method should not contain more than one page of code.  Break it up in smaller private helper methods.

Comment: I would love this feature/extension too. My methods aren't huge, but I have poor eyesight. This would help.

Comment: You shouldn't write long methods is the level of wisdom that warrants two upvotes? That comment in no ways answers this question. That comment makes an assumption and then answers it with a non-answer.

Answer (score 0):

If its to make the code easier to navigate, try using the #region command:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9a1ybwek%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

If its to highlight something you want to come back and fix later, use // TODO etc which will be added to the VS Task list:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zce12xx2%28v=vs.100%29.aspx